# How to write your own .net obfuscator

Tags: .net, obfuscation

I am very curious as to how people write their own obfuscator.

How hard would it be to simply do the following:

1. rename all public methods with GUID type names.

Where would I start?  How would I go about reading the .net dll assemby, pulling the public methods out and renaming them?

Comment: Hi Blankman, could you either request more informations, or accept an answer?

Answer (score 7):

You can check those two projects that are using [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to write an open-source obfuscator:

- http://code.google.com/p/obfuscar/
- http://www.codeplex.com/SharpObfuscator

Answer (score 3):

[Jason Haley has some great links...](http://jasonhaley.com/Obfuscation/)

Comment: Plz provide an available Link

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting with source, it's pretty simple to do text replacements and then run the code through a compiler.  If you are starting with a compiled assembly, then you need to use the stuff in the System.Reflection namespace to load the assembly and System.CodeDom to generate compilable code units.

Comment: but how would you write a new version of the assembly after doing reflection on the original assembly.

Comment: Doing the source code replacement is not at all easy, at least not automatically. Global search & replace is useless: it will, for example, also "obfuscate" parts of the strings, and calls to methods in external libraries that happen to have the same name as a method in your assembly.